# How to properly recalculate a boolean whenever the input observable changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a component to which I pass an object as its input.

That object comes from an API, so it is not available right away. And the object returned from the API can also be empty.

In the template, I want to hide the value unless it is not an empty object.

So I have this in my component:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { not, isEmpty } from "ramda";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    {{ hasName | async }} {{ name | async }}
    <h1 *ngIf="(hasName | async)">Hello {{ name | async }}!</h1>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: Observable<{} | { first: string }> = of({});
  hasName: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name.pipe(
      tap(name => console.log(name)),
      // the actual logic to calculate the boolean is quite involved, but I  
      // have simplified it here for brevity.
      tap(name => this.hasName.next(not(isEmpty(name)))) 
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the console.log in the tap is never printed and the second tap is never run either, so the value for `hasName` is always `false` as set at the of the class.

I think what happens is that in OnInit, this.name is still `of({})`, and not the actual observable passed in through the template from the parent.

I am using `of({})` because typing `this.name` as `Observable<{} | { first: string}> | undefined` leads to more boilerplate in the class to check it is indeed defined before using it.

How can I make this work in an idiomatic way?

Complete Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxqh2d?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe to this observable in `ngOnInit`?

Comment: I'd like to avoid that, so that I don't have to unsubscribe in OnDestroy. I remember reading it's best to only using async pipes and avoid subscribing explicity.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest passing `name | async` in `app` component to your `hello` component instead of passing whole observable. Then you can just check value inside your child component. It would be much easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this code a lot.

First off all, the TS definition.

```
{} | { first: string }
```

Can be done as

```
{ first?: string }
```

While it may look like I'm doing some neat picking here I'm not really. With the first option if you try to access variable.first you'll get an error saying it doesn't exist as the union cannot guarantee this. With the latter it's fine.

Then, the mock. When working with observables, try not to reassign observable. Here's how you can do what you where doing without reassigning:

```
  public name$: Observable<{ first?: string }> = concat(
    of({}),
    interval(2000).pipe(
      map(() => ({
        first: `${Math.random()}`
      }))
    )
  );
```

Finally, the child component. Passing observables as input is a code smell in 99% of the cases. Here all you want is a presentational component (also called dumb component).

This dumb component should not have any logic (as much as possible at least), and here's what you can do:

```
type Nil = null | undefined

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="name?.first">Hello {{ name.first }}!</h1>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: { first?: string } | Nil;
}
```

Which means that when you call this from the parent, you just do:

```html
<hello [name]="name$ | async"></hello>
```

Here's an updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hnv23a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: In simplifying my example, I dumbed it down too much maybe. The usual pattern is that the component is getting some kind of ID as its input, which it must then use to query an API with to get the name object. So when I instantiate the component and the variable, I don't know what that ID is, and I cant do `this.myService.getNameFor(id)`, which is why I do `of('')` and then reassign to the API call in OnInit once I know the ID.

Comment: There's no `this.myService.getNameFor` in your example. Please provide more info if you want further help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react when the input value changes you can write your own setter:

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() set name(name: Observable<{} | { first: string }>) {
    this.name$ = name.pipe(
      tap(name => console.log(name)),
      tap(name => this.hasName.next(not(isEmpty(name))))
    );
  }

  name$: Observable<{} | { first: string }>;

  ...
}
```

Then in templates bind `async` to `name$` instead.

Updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7u7xkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: While this is technically correct and can be useful from time to time, I believe the overall code can be simplified a lot and is not following good practices. Instead of doing all this we can take advantage of the "Safe Navigation Operator" which is the `?` to simply do `*ngIf="name?.first"`. There's no need to use any observable in the child component IMO

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to move your logic to `app.component.ts` instead of passing  the whole observable into an input. This could help you to manage the value of that input and prevent assigning a value to it two times (you have assigned an empty object two times in your code - parent & child component).

Simplest thing to make your code work is just to subscribe to the observable you've created inside your `ngOnInit`:

```
this.name.pipe(
  tap(name => console.log(name)),
  tap(name => this.hasName.next(not(isEmpty(name)))) 
).subscribe();
```

In case you don't want to manage that (don't want to be worried about non destroyed observables) and you prefer to use the `async` pipe, you can just reassign `this.name` inside `ngOnInit`.

```
this.name = this.name.pipe(
  tap(name => console.log(name)),
  tap(name => this.hasName.next(not(isEmpty(name)))) 
);
```

Comment: Subscribe is where reactive programming ends. Avoid subscribing within components as much as possible. Components should be dealing with how data are being retrieved, it's not their role. They should just have access to observables that are providing data over time and therefore it should be just fine to use the async pipe instead. Also, there's absolutely no need to reassign an observable within the ngOnInit hook. Just define it as a class variable once and for all. Observables are cold by nature, you'll only subscribe to it when the view is ready if you use the async pipe anyway

Comment: That said, I don't think there's any need to have a `hasName` variable. Using the safe navigation operator from angular `?` is sufficient and super easy IMO

Comment: Sure, I've said that I'd suggest to move logic to parent component, but also provided a way to achieve goal in way OP was trying to succeed.

Comment: Make sense :) !